# Problems syncing purchased music from iPad to Mac iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipad, mac, music

I have purchased music on the iPad but it does not appear in the "bought" section on my Mac's iTunes.

It doesn't make any sense! Everything is fully updated (except for my Mac's OS which is OS X Lion)

Why is this happening and how can I get it to sync?

Answer (score 1):

Have you authorised your Mac's iTunes for the iTunes account used to purchase the Music?

[Apple's KB article on transferring and authorising](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1848?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Comment: Also, have you checked yes to the iTunes preference, Download purchased items automatically?